# GSP Editing in Netbeans 6.8

Tags: netbeans, groovy, format, gsp, indentation

I have a problem with Netbeans 6.8 and GSP pages. Format and indent working but provides invalid structure.

Moreover Netbeans highlinging page directive as error.

And code completion is not working too.

Is it a bug or smth need to be fixed in my settings or Netbeans does not provide such features.

In this [archive](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1852467/indent.rar) you can find screenshots of the code. First it was indented with **IntelliJIdea** and then reformated with **Netbeans**. Yoy can notice invalid indentation near **<g: .../>** tags.

Thanks, Vova.

Comment: I've cleaned all directories, regester and any mention about Netbeans. Then I reinstall it. Nothing changed.

Comment: Looks like it's a bug:
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=168004

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed most of those issues in the NetBeans codebase.

Related tickets from NetBeans bugzilla:
http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=168004
http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=202248

Would be great if you could try them and provide some feedback to NB development team.